# How can I disable email verification for social authentication on parse.com?

Tags: javascript, php, parse-platform

I have 2 different ways to sign up on a website, email and Facebook. While I need the email to be verified for the email signup, I don't want it for Facebook signup.

Is there a way to disable it for Facebook logins and registrations? I've tried setting the `emailVerified` property to `true` manually, but that didn't work.

Comment: Same problem. Have you found a solution?